# can't understand quartz schedule expression

Tags: spring, quartz-scheduler

Spring quartz schedule expression

```
0 40 4-16 * * *
```

Java spring scheduler quartz

I have old code with express schedule="0 40 4-16 * * *" i do not understand what does that mean ?

Even after readying the following file can't figure out what does above Cron expression do. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It will run every day on 4:40, 5:40, 6:40, ... 16:40. Simple test code:

```
import org.springframework.scheduling.support.CronSequenceGenerator;


CronSequenceGenerator cron = new CronSequenceGenerator("0 40 4-16 * * *", TimeZone.getDefault());
Date d = new Date();
for (int i = 0; i < 20; ++i) {
    d = cron.next(d);
    System.out.println(d);
}
```

<sup>or [this](http://nurkiewicz.blogspot.no/2012/10/testing-quartz-cron-expressions.html) for Quartz API.</sup>